# What's causing this error in my code?

Tags: vb.net

I am making a quiz for my computer science class and the basic concept is that you have 15 keywords and 15 definitions. All need to be randomly displayed and the correct answer has to appear. The user has to match the correct definition to the keyword twice and then that keyword and definition are not displayed again. When all have been answered twice the quiz is over.

I have stored both my keywords and my definitions in the same file so they don't get out of sync. The text file looks like so:

```
Keyword1,Definition1
Keyword2,Definition2
Keyword3,Definition3
...
```

The issue I am getting is with two lines in my code. First I shall reference all relevant code to make what I am asking as clear as possible. I have created a class `Answer` and that looks like this:

```
Public Class Answer
Public Answer As String
Public Answered As Boolean
```

`End Class`
My main form `form1` looks like this:

```
Public Class Form1
Const NUMBER_OF_ANSWERS As Integer = 3

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    kv = New Dictionary(Of String, Answer)
    For Each line As String In IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\Matt\Documents\keywords.txt")
        Dim parts() As String = line.Split(",")
        kv.Add(parts(0), New Answer With {.Answer = parts(1), .Answered = False})
    Next

    Dim r As New Random
    Dim kvRandom As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String)) =
      kv.OrderBy(Function() r.Next).ToList

    'questions will appear in random order
    For Each line As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In kvRandom
        Dim keyword As String = line.Key
        Dim correctDefinition As String = line.Value

        Dim keywords As New List(Of String)
        keywords.Add(keyword)
        keywords.AddRange(kv.Keys.Except({keyword}).
          OrderBy(Function() r.Next).Take(NUMBER_OF_ANSWERS - 1))

        Dim definitionsRandom As List(Of String) =
          keywords.Select(Function(x) kv(x)).OrderBy(Function() r.Next).ToList

        LabelKeyword.Text = keyword
        RadioButtonDef1.Text = definitionsRandom(0)
        RadioButtonDef2.Text = definitionsRandom(1)
        RadioButtonDef3.Text = definitionsRandom(2)
    Next

End Sub
```

My error is on the following two lines:

`kv.OrderBy(Function() r.Next).ToList` which is:

`Error 1   Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of String, flashquiz.Answer))' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of String, String))'.   C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\flashquiz\flashquiz\Form1.vb  62  11  flashquiz`
 and

`keywords.Select(Function(x) kv(x)).OrderBy(Function() r.Next).ToList` which is:

`Error  2   Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of flashquiz.Answer)' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)'.   C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\flashquiz\flashquiz\Form1.vb  75  15  flashquiz`

I'm not sure what is wrong, so any help will be greatly appreciated.
I know that it's to do with the Answer class but not exactly what.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first offending line is here:

```
Dim kvRandom As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String)) =
  kv.OrderBy(Function() r.Next).ToList
```

In this line, you are taking all of the items in `kv`, sorting them randomly, and returning them as a `List(Of Answer)`.  You are then trying to assign that list to the `kvRandom` variable which is declared as `List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String))`.  Since those two types are incompatible, it is giving you the error.

To fix it, you need to either change `kvRandom` to be declared as `List(Of Answer)`, like this:

```
Dim kvRandom As List(Of Answer) = kv.OrderBy(Function() r.Next).ToList()
```

Or, you need to add a `Select` method to convert the items in the list properly, for instance:

```
Dim kvRandom As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String)) =
    kv.OrderBy(Function() r.Next) _
    .Select(Function(x) New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)(x.Key, x.Value.Answer)) _
    .ToList()
```

---

The second offending line is here:

```
Dim definitionsRandom As List(Of String) =
      keywords.Select(Function(x) kv(x)).OrderBy(Function() r.Next).ToList
```

The `Select` method is returning a list of items returned by the lambda expression `Function(x) kv(x)`.  Since `kv` is a `Dictionary(Of String, Answer)`, that means `kv(x)` will return an `Answer` object.  Therefore, the `Select` method is returning a list of `Answer` objects.  You are then sorting it in random order and converting it to a `List(Of Answer)` object.  Then you try to assign that to the `definitionsRandom` variable, which is a `List(Of String)`.  Since they are two different incompatible types, it is giving you the error.

To fix it, you need to change your lambda expression in your call to the `Select` method to return a `String` rather than an `Answer` object.  For instance:

```
Dim definitionsRandom As List(Of String) =
      keywords.Select(Function(x) kv(x).Answer).OrderBy(Function() r.Next).ToList
```

Notice, the lambda expression is returning `kv(x).Answer` rather than `kv(x)`.

Comment: Thank you that fixed that line however I still seem to have an issue with the other one: `kv.OrderBy(Function() r.Next).ToList` How can I fix that one?